# how to change font-family for email templates in magento 2.4.5-p2

Tags: email-templates, magento2.4.5, fonts, font-family

I am using "Olegnax Athlete2" theme for my magento2.4.5-p2 store. I want to change my email template fonts to "futura pt book". can someone guide me to do the same.